# How to extend Approximal Medial Axis both sides

Tags: postgis

I would like to extend lines created with the function ST_ApproximalMedial_Axis to 2 points, located each side of this line.
Each line is the medial axis of a polygon created by the intersection of 2 buffers and the points are the points of intersection of these buffers.

```
    -- Creation of axis
    CREATE TABLE public.l_axe_med AS
    SELECT
    row_number() OVER () as id_axe,
    t3.idu1,
    t3.idu2,
    ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(t3.geom) geom
    FROM (
    SELECT t1.idu as idu1, t2.idu as idu2, ST_INTERSECTION(t1.geom, t2.geom) geom
    FROM public.tb_buffer_initial t1
    INNER JOIN public.tb_buffer_initial t2
    ON ST_INTERSECTS(t1.geom, t2.geom) IS TRUE AND t1.geom && t2.geom
    WHERE t1.id_ilot != t2.id_ilot and t1.idu1 != t2.idu2) t3

    -- Creation of the points of intersection

    CREATE TABLE public.p_interbuf AS SELECT
    row_number() OVER () as id_interbuf,
    t1.id_buf as id_buf1,
    t2.id_buf as id_buf2,
    t1.idu as idu1,
    t2.idu as idu2,
    ST_INTERSECTION(ST_BOUNDARY(t1.geom),ST_BOUNDARY(t2.geom)) geom, 
    ST_GeometryType(ST_INTERSECTION(ST_BOUNDARY(t1.geom),ST_BOUNDARY(t2.geom))) as type_geom
    FROM 
    public.tb_buffer_v2 t1
    INNER JOIN public.tb_buffer_v2 t2
    ON ST_INTERSECTS(t1.geom, t2.geom) IS TRUE AND t1.geom && t2.geom
    WHERE t1.id_ilot != t2.id_ilot and t1.idu != t2.idu and t1.id_buf != t2.id_buf
```

I imagine there will be a call of the function ST_Closest... but I have for the moment no idea of how to proceed. May you help me please ?

---

I've found a part of the answer with the following request

```
SELECT 
id_axe,
idu1,
idu2,
CASE WHEN ST_Distance(ST_StartPoint(axe_geom), geomp1) < ST_Distance(ST_StartPoint(axe_geom), geomp2) 
THEN ST_MakeLine(array[ST_MakeLine(geomp1, ST_StartPoint(axe_geom)), axe_geom, ST_MakeLine(ST_EndPoint(axe_geom), geomp2)])
ELSE ST_MakeLine(array[geomp2, axe_geom, geomp1]) END as geom
FROM (
SELECT
id_axe,
idu1,
idu2,
axe_geom,
ST_GeometryN(multipoint_geom, 1) as geomp1,
ST_GeometryN(multipoint_geom, 2) as geomp2,
ST_NPoints(t4.multipoint_geom) as nb_path
FROM
(SELECT
row_number() OVER () as id_axe,
t3.idu1,
t3.idu2,
ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(t3.poly_geom) as axe_geom,
t3.multipoint_geom
FROM (
SELECT t1.idu as idu1, t2.idu as idu2, ST_INTERSECTION(t1.geom, t2.geom) as poly_geom, ST_INTERSECTION(ST_BOUNDARY(t1.geom), ST_BOUNDARY(t2.geom)) as multipoint_geom
FROM public.tb_buffer_initial t1
INNER JOIN public.tb_buffer_initial t2
ON ST_INTERSECTS(t1.geom, t2.geom) IS TRUE AND t1.geom && t2.geom
WHERE t1.id_ilot != t2.id_ilot and t1.idu != t2.idu) t3) t4) t5
```

But whatever the case, the line that is created is a the line between the intersections of boundaries although I Would like to use the true geometry of my medial axis.

And when I use ST_Union I only get back the medial axis, but it is not extended to the boundaries

```
THEN ST_Union(array[ST_MakeLine(geomp1, ST_StartPoint(axe_geom)), axe_geom, ST_MakeLine(ST_EndPoint(axe_geom), geomp2)])
ELSE ST_Union(array[ST_MakeLine(geomp2, ST_StartPoint(axe_geom)), axe_geom, ST_MakeLine(ST_EndPoint(axe_geom), geomp1)]) END as geom
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the request

```
CREATE TABLE public.l_axemed AS
SELECT 
id_axe,
idu1,
idu2,
CASE WHEN ST_Distance(ST_StartPoint(ST_LineMerge(axe_geom)), geomp1) < ST_Distance(ST_StartPoint(ST_LineMerge(axe_geom)), geomp2) 
THEN ST_Union(array[ST_MakeLine(geomp1, ST_StartPoint(ST_LineMerge(axe_geom))), ST_LineMerge(axe_geom), ST_MakeLine(ST_EndPoint(ST_LineMerge(axe_geom)), geomp2)])
ELSE ST_Union(array[ST_MakeLine(geomp2, ST_StartPoint(ST_LineMerge(axe_geom))), ST_LineMerge(axe_geom), ST_MakeLine(ST_EndPoint(ST_LineMerge(axe_geom)), geomp1)]) END as geom
FROM (
SELECT
id_axe,
idu1,
idu2,
axe_geom,
ST_GeometryN(multipoint_geom, 1) as geomp1,
ST_GeometryN(multipoint_geom, 2) as geomp2,
ST_NPoints(t4.multipoint_geom) as nb_path
FROM
(SELECT
row_number() OVER () as id_axe,
t3.idu1,
t3.idu2,
ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(t3.poly_geom) as axe_geom,
t3.multipoint_geom
FROM (
SELECT t1.idu as idu1, t2.idu as idu2, ST_INTERSECTION(t1.geom, t2.geom) as poly_geom, ST_INTERSECTION(ST_BOUNDARY(t1.geom), ST_BOUNDARY(t2.geom)) as multipoint_geom
FROM taxes.tb_buffer_initial t1
INNER JOIN taxes.tb_buffer_initial t2
ON ST_INTERSECTS(t1.geom, t2.geom) IS TRUE AND t1.geom && t2.geom
WHERE t1.id_ilot != t2.id_ilot and t1.idu != t2.idu) t3) t4) t5
```